# Python beautifulSoup loops

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to assign the URL from a specific iteration (in the 'position' variable) of a for loop to a variable using BeautifulSoup, and I can't see why it's not working (the output is the full list - I only want the selected one). Any help wld much appreciated. Thanks!

```
position = int(input('Enter position:'))
n = int(0)

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    if n<position:
        n=n+1
    else:
        x=tag.get('href', None)
        print(x)
```

Comment: `tags = soup('a')` I think you want `tags = soup.find_all('a')` instead...

Comment: Thanks a lot John. This would have worked I think - I did eventually end up using get:                                                                                                                               
url = input('Enter URL:')
position = int((input('Enter position:')))-1
count = int((input('Enter Count:')))-1
n = int(0)

while n <= count:
    n=n+1
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    x=tags[position].get('href', None)
    url = x
    print(x)

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid a loop and pass position as value for limit argument with .select() method of soup object.

select returns a list of elements matched by the css selector list passed in e.g. anchor tags selected by `a` type selector. limit stops matching at the specified number. -1 index returns last match from returned list i.e. at the desired position. 0-indexing.

```
position = int(input('Enter position:'))
result = soup.select('a', limit=position)[-1]['href']
print(result)
```

Comment: To make more robust you would want to add try except block in case limit is greater than the number of available elements that could be matched.